# Are there any options in Libre office to save files directly in Google Drive by default?

Tags: libreoffice

Are there any options in LibreOffice to save files directly in Google Drive by default?
Other than Oog2google extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unaware of any such option. However, a simple way to accomplish the same objective is to install InSync (more info and download/installation instructions on [this page](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/insync-brings-google-drive-to-ubuntu)) and save documents directly from LibreOffice into your new '/home/InSync' folder. When you run InSync, any files in this folder will be uploaded to your Google Drive.

Comment: Thanx.. Can we access the files even in offline?

Comment: @Abhishek: yes.

Comment: Sure can. InSync fills the '/home/InSync' folder with local copies of all of the documents on your Google Drive, so they can be accessed and edited anytime. Running InSync will update both Google Drive and the '/home/InSync/' folder so that they both contain the newest version of every document.

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice plugin ooo2g works on Libre Office too and might be what you're looking for.

To install, first of all you need to get the libreoffice java common package

```
sudo apt-get install openoffice.org-java-common
```

Then you can download the extension from the official site

http://code.google.com/p/ooo2gd/downloads/list

And finally install it from libreoffice, opening

> Tools -> Extension Manager -> Add

Now close and re-open libreoffice and you will se a new floating menu, which is able to export your document directly to GoogleDocs

Comment: Thanks, But it is not working

Comment: What problem do you have? Trouble installing?

Answer (score 0):

You can save officelibre docs directly to Google drive. Google offers different strategies to sync documents (or document folders) between Google Docs and Google Drive.